# Visual Studio: which setting to change for Find Next results in text editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Consider the Visual Studio's highly-customizable configuration of the text editor.

The value I'd like to tweak is the **highlighting of the found search string**. See circled below.

**Question:** in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, or Visual Studio 2008 which setting in the Fonts and Colors dialog box will allow the **highlight/surround color to be changed**?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing **Colors->Selected Text** and **Colors->Inactive Selected Text** (in Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts)

Comment: (For anyone reading this using VS2010 RTM: Use **Active Selected Text** instead of inactive selected text, as the bug that required changing the inactive selection color has since been fixed)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Beta 2 that the results of a Find operation are highlighted with the inactive selection color instead of the active selection color (as Orcas did).  Post Beta 2, it should show up in the much more obvious blue (or whatever the active selection color is set to).

Other than that, it isn't separately configurable, as the highlight is the actual text selection and not a marker of some sort.

Comment: @Noah - thank you for this answer. I'll keep in mind that the Active Selection's color will be the one used in highlighting in the future. Thank you!